# Searching a string to find an email address in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write code that will let me search the content submitted through a form and find the email address in the content.  Below is the code, and the error message I'm receiving.

```
Error: undefined method `match' for {"content"=>"this is a test testemail@gmail.com"}:ActionController::Parameters
```

Code:

```
class ChallengesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @challenge = current_user.challenges.build(challenge_params)
    challenge_params.match(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i)
    # ...
  end

  private

  def challenge_params
    params.require(:challenge).permit(:content)
  end 
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Using regular expressions to find valid email strings is very difficult, because there are [a huge number of variations on valid addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).

Answer (score 1):

You are applying `match` on a Hash.

`challenge_params` is a Hash. Going by the error message, this hash contains a key `content` which is where you want to use with `match`, hence rewriting the `match` line to:

```
challenge_params["content"].match(/\b[A-Z0-9\._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i)
```

Comment: Also, the regex is not correct - `.` has to be escaped in both `[]`.

Comment: didnt notice that. Thanks will update it in my answer

Comment: @BroiSatse this is wrong. Dot *does not* need escaping inside square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to ruby so my answer may be very "amateur-ish", but sometimes the simplest ideas are the best...
The way I would do this is search for index of @ sign. Then analyze each character before and after the sign until you get to blank space and save those index numbers. Use those index numbers to extract the email address from your string.

```
def email_address(str)
at_index = str.index('@')
temp = (at_index - 1)
while str[temp] != ' '
    temp -= 1
end
begining_index = (temp + 1)
temp = (at_index + 1)
while str[temp] != ' '
    temp += 1
end
end_index = temp
return str[begining_index..end_index]
```

end

Comment: problem with this approach is, what if you get a string like: `"some random special chars 1@#$%! my email: test@gmail.com"`

Comment: While the description is nice, you need to show code. We appreciate that you're new to Ruby, however solutions to problems almost always need code.

Comment: @theTinMan: sorry about that. I edited my original answer including sample code...